# Regular expression for unlimited digits but limited other character

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to find a regular expression for unlimited digits but limited underscores.

So let's say `max_underscore = 3`.

Then

`123_456_678` is ok (3 underscores)
`1234213_2132135678` is ok (2 underscores)

But

`13_4156_7_012_1` is not ok (4 underscores)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Comment: FWIW, you don't need regex, most languages have a way to find number of occurances of a character in a string.

Comment: That being said, what language/tool are you actually using?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen php

Comment: @Sayse yes. but in this case need this in the regex

Comment: Then you should try it yourself first and then include your attempts in your question.

Comment: Is it allowed to have underscore at the begining or at the end of the string? Is it allowed to have 2 or more underscores consecutive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If underscore is not allowed at the begining or at the end and it is not allowed to have 2 or more consecutive underscore:

```
^(?:\d+_?){3}\d+$
```

If underscore is allowed at the begining or at the end:

```
^(?:\d*_?){3}\d*$
```

These regex match string that have 0 upto 3 underscore but not more.

See these 2 regexes in action:

```
$strings = array(
'123456',
'1_2_3_456',
'123_456',
'_123_456_',
'1_2_3_4_5_6',
'123___456',
);
$num = 3;
echo 'using "^(?:\d+_?){3}\d+$"',"\n";
foreach($strings as $string) {
    if (preg_match("/^(?:\d+_?){".$num."}\d+$/", $string)) {
        echo "OK: $string\n";
    } else {
        echo "KO: $string\n";
    }
}
echo 'using "^(?:\d*_?){3}\d*$"',"\n";

foreach($strings as $string) {
    if (preg_match("/^(?:\d*_?){".$num."}\d*$/", $string)) {
        echo "OK: $string\n";
    } else {
        echo "KO: $string\n";
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
using "^(?:\d+_?){3}\d+$"
OK: 123456
OK: 1_2_3_456
OK: 123_456
KO: _123_456_
KO: 1_2_3_4_5_6
KO: 123___456
using "^(?:\d*_?){3}\d*$"
OK: 123456
OK: 1_2_3_456
OK: 123_456
OK: _123_456_
KO: 1_2_3_4_5_6
OK: 123___456
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can, represent each of the other characters.

For example with 3 underscores :

```
\d*_\d*_\d*_\d*
```

If you want to match 3 or less underscores, you can make parts of the regex optional :

```
\d*(_\d*(_\d*(_\d*)?)?)?
```

Note that this allow two consecutive underscores and underscores at the start and end of the string, which you could avoid by using `+` instead of `*` :

```
\d+_\d+_\d+_\d+
```

Comment: Doesn't match string with less than 3 underscore as requested.